# What is the reason for web application not found

Tags: 2013

When using spsite api i get this,

> Unable to obtain meeting details for this user ---> The Web
>   application at
>   https://portal.fruitfactory.com/sites/hr/internal/457/16709/ could not
>   be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL
>   should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need
>   to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

I can go to url using browser. if add it to hosts file then why ?

Running it on my server installed with sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

The SPSite object is part of the server-side API and will only run successfully on the server. If you are attempting to run this code outside of the SharePoint server, you will get an error similar to the one you are seeing. You will need to use one of SharePoint's client-side object models or REST/OData endpoints to accomplish what you are doing.

Reference:
[Choose the right API set in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj164060.aspx)

Comment: I am using it on my server